# MySQL returning two rows with same data under different keys

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL returning two rows with same data under different keys.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => Good
    [name] => Good
    [2] => 1.jpg
    [path] => 1.jpg
)
```

The thing i'm talking about is [0] and [id] have the same data and it returned directly from the query why is this and is there a way to fix it to just return the string key.

My query function.

```
<?php

class Database
{

    private static $connection = null;

    public function Connect()
    {
        self::$connection = mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "", "image");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { die("Failed to connect to MySQL"); }
    }

    public function custome($query)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query(self::$connection, $query);
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $resultArray[] = $item; } return $resultArray[0];
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: this is not problem with mysql this is problem with the language you are using and the qay you are queering for example php

Comment: @A.B that irrelevant i'm asking for a fix to my problem.  And I know its php thats why I asked...

Comment: @RyleeHarrison problem was with php thats what i was pointing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` to retrieve assocaitive(key/value) array

```
 public function custome($query)
  {
            $result = mysqli_query(self::$connection, $query);
            while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
             {
                  $resultArray[] = $item; 
             } 
     return $resultArray[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `mysqli_fetch_array` it defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH` which returns both numerical and associative indexes.
You probably want either `MYSQLI_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`, not the default `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Alternately, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` which defaults to an associative array.

Here's the relevant documentation:

- [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
- [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score -2):

You can reference an array, called an "association", by identifying the key/value pair of the associative array.  The item location in the array is a number `myarray[n-1]` where n is the size of the array.